# Visit visa to Bermuda

Tags: visas

The official Site of Bermuda government states the following :

"As of 1 March 2014, Bermuda entry visas and visa waivers will no longer be required for tourist and business visitors and work permit holders.

To be landed in Bermuda, the following requirements must be met:

1. all travellers who require a multi re-entry visa (MRV) must present this visa-type upon arrival in Bermuda;
2. the MRV for the UK, US or Canada must be valid for 45 days after the expiration of a visitor stay and/or of the work permit; and
3. all travellers must possess a passport that is valid for 45 days past the expiration of travel and/or of the work permit (Note: US Passport Cards are not permitted for use for travel to Bermuda by air)"

To my understanding, you need any sort of multi-entry visa for US/UK/CANDA if transitting through these countries, which will always be the case?

More importantly, can someone explain what the first line legally means with all its nuances. I might be overthinking it but I don't want to waste expensive tickets.

I have F1-visa btw for US and is multientry.

Thanks

Comment: Whatever the current Bermuda passport/visa/transit rules might be (the page you cite is more than six years old, and may well be out of date), you'll also have to address Bermuda's COVID-related requirements as well. Start here: https://www.gov.bm/coronavirus-travellers